# JOI reports "AssertionError: Invalid schema content"

Tags: node.js, joi

Here is the error after I added `.unique` to `order schema` with `platform_order_id`:

```
AssertionError: Invalid schema content: (platform_order_id)
```

Here is `function validateOrder`:

```
function validateOrder(order) {
    const schema = {
    customer_name: Joi.string()
        .required(),
    amount_rmb: Joi.number()
        .precision(2)
        .required(), 
    amount_crypto: Joi.number()
        .precision(2)
        .required(), 
    platform_order_id: Joi.number()
        .required()
        .unique,  //<== causing error
    x_rate: Joi.number()
        .required()
    };
    return Joi.validate(order, schema);
};
```

The `order.platform_order_id` is `149345`. Tried `Number('149345')` and the error is the same. Without `.unique`, the validate works fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.unique()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.0.4/API.md#arrayuniquecomparator-options) is for `Array` type, not for `Number` type.

and system level `uniqueness` should be validated after joi validation, I think.

Comment: I thought the uniqueness is something JOI can check.

Comment: joi can validate uniqueness for a given data. but I understand op just want to validate uniqueness in a system level. joi can't validate `platform_order_id` is unique in system.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
The solution to this problem is to swap the parameters, like this=>
return Joi.validate(schema, order);
The first parameter should be schema then the second parameter is the data to validate.
For Reference visit here:
[LINK](https://www.mindbowser.com/object-validation/#:%7E:text=object()%20method%2C%20and%20then,the%20status%20of%20the%20API)

I need to address something in advance, after filling in the input fields if your submit button is not enabled then you need to swap the parameters again back to the same position, i.e. the first parameter "data to validate" then the second parameter "schema", then you will be able to submit the form.
for example
 `const result = Joi.validate(this.state.account, this.schema);`